# How to get sound working in pure DOS with a CMI8330 card?

Tags: ms-dos, sound

I have a tower PC from the early 2000's. I got this system second-hand and as-is so I do not have any original driver resources. I have installed Windows 95 mainly to play old Windows and DOS games.

Recently, I have fiddled around trying to get sound working as there were no working drivers installed. The hardware manager told me that my onboard sound card is a CMI8330, for which I [found a driver online](https://driverscollection.com/?file_id=1642) and managed to get it installed. Now, the Windows part of the machine has working sound (start-up sound, in-game sound in *Settlers II*).

I had hoped for sound to magically appear for the DOS game (*Crystal Caves*) that I was playing, too. (I know that sound exists as I remember playing the exact same diskette on a different PC and having sound in the day.) However, that did not happen. Googling told me, there needs to be a `SET BLASTER=` line in the `autoexec.bat` which wasn’t there. I did my best to look up the required values for the sound card and tried entering them. All in all, my `autoexec.bat` now looks like this:

```
mode con codepage prepare ((850) C:\WINDOWS\COMMAND\ega.cpi)
mode con codepage select=850
keyb gr,,C:\WINDOWS\COMMAND\keyboard.sys
SET BLASTER=A220 I5 D1 T6 H5
```

I have tried a number of different `T` values to no avail. I am confident that `A`, `I` and `D` are correct as entered (I did not modify the default values in the driver settings but did find those exact ones).

What else might I try to get sound working for the DOS game? Is there something I may have completely missed?

(In case it wasn’t obvious: I am accessing DOS by restarting into MS-DOS mode; the good old Win95 feature.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To configure your CMI-8330 sound card under plain DOS, without Windows, you need to install the CMI-8330 initialisation tool. You can download it [from HelpDrivers](https://www.helpdrivers.com/sound/C-Media/CMI_8330/) (scroll down, look for `c30dos12.zip`), or from [the VOGONS vintage driver library](https://www.vogonsdrivers.com/getfile.php?fileid=685&menustate=0).

Extract the archive and run `INSTALL.EXE` from plain DOS; when it asks for a Windows 3 installation directory, skip the Windows installation by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will set everything up so that sound works under DOS.

This might not help for Crystal Caves however; it only uses the PC speaker. If your motherboard emulates the PC speaker using the CMI-8330 (if that’s possible), you’ll find relevant settings in the utilities described above; otherwise, you might need to find an appropriate speaker and connect it to the corresponding motherboard header.

You may also need to enable sound effects in the game: start Crystal Caves, then start a game, and inside the game, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get the in-game menu, <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle sound, and <kbd>Y</kbd> to enable sound:

[image: The Crystal Caves in-game menu]

[image: Crystal Caves sound toggle]

Comment: Okay, so if the game accesses the speaker, why is it not and what am I doing wrong? Because I’m relatively sure I heard that PC beep before … (Although that probably opens another can of worms …)

Comment: Does it beep when you switch it on?

Comment: I don’t think connecting the PC speaker wires to the regular sound card became popular until the latter half of the 2000s at the very least, and even then, I think it was primarily in laptops. A sound card old enough to have DOS drivers probably doesn’t have a dedicated PC speaker input (though <http://hw.fagear.ru/wp-content/uploads/20140811_717528.jpg> and <https://http2.mlstatic.com/placa-som-cmi8330-para-slot-i-s-a-3d-funcionando-100-D_NQ_NP_804497-MLB27394821987_052018-F.jpg> do show _some_ kind of pins where a speaker _might_ be connected, if one is so inclined).

Comment: @StephenKitt Affirmative.

Comment: @Jan Have you toggled sound on within the game? Can you install FreeCOM and run its `BEEP` command to see if that works? (Or use `DEBUG` to reprogram the speaker manually?)

Comment: @user3840170 it was reasonably common on Sound Blaster cards (commonly labeled “PC_SPK”), and some cards like the PAS16 could take over PC speaker duties without even being connected to the motherboard header. Quite a few Dell systems I used in the mid- to late-nineties handled the PC speaker using their sound card.

Comment: +1 I have a CMI8330 card, and it does need a driver in the autoexec to make it work like a SB card. As for the PC speaker issues, a good game to test your PC speaker with is ZZT. It never shuts up. :)

Comment: @user3840170 I haven’t heard about FreeCOM and there are multiple different things that show up when I google it; also, I am not acquainted enough with DOS to know how to beep with `DEBUG`, sorry … As for toggling sound, I cannot find an option in-game.

Comment: @Jan Sorry, I meant the command-line interpreter of FreeDOS, i.e. <https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/base/freecom.zip>. Never mind `DEBUG`, it’s rather intricate even for the knowledgeable. Though if you have the Windows 95 CD, you should be able to find QBASIC on it somewhere (IIRC), which has a `PLAY` statement which can also be used to test the PC speaker.

Comment: @user3840170 I found out between my last comment and this that I was looking for the sound toggle in the main menu rather than during a game. Toggling sound on worked from within the main level but I expected an option from the main menu … I’ll admit, I feel a little stupid now. I’m just confused why sound was off by default rather than on as I had remembered it … but that’s certainly not a question for the comment section ;)

Comment: @Jan excellent, I take it your sound problems are resolved now, right?

Comment: @Jan No worries, it still produced a good Q&A pair. Maybe it will be useful to someone else coming later.

Answer (score 2):

**All** the non-original Creative Labs Sound Blaster sound cards I saw back in the day **required to initialize them with some executable(s)** that was part of the sound driver, which you are not doing at all. This was done either in AUTOEXEC.BAT or CONFIG.SYS or both. Even newer Creative Lab Sound Blasters need such a thing.

After searching my archives, I found out that for CMEDIA CMI8330 sound cards, the DOS driver executables are:

```
C3DMIX.COM
SETAUDIO.COM
FIXEPIC.EXE
```

I cannot test them as I no longer have a CMI8330 card on board working, and both *.COM executables throw message on me that PCI CMI8330 card is not present. The last EXE is just some fix for some games and not a driver.

If you do not have such files then try to download them; this is the first Google hit that looks promising (contains the SETAUDIO.COM file in listing): [CMedia DOS Mode MPU-401 Emulator Driver](https://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=537023).

According to [VOGONS: cmi8738 pci - dos (no FX)](https://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=18928), you should add this to your `autoexec.bat`:

```
C:\PCIAUD\SETAUDIO
SET BLASTER=A220 I5 D1 H5 T4
C:\PCIAUD\C3DMIX /MFF000 /FFF000 /WFF000 /L00100 /E00100 /A00100 /C00100 /P00000 /400000 /R0f0ff /D040ff /Q0
```

But its possible that the driver executables will make that entries on their own once executed.

In case you have no luck on finding those driver files, comment me and I will post them somewhere.

Another option is to install the awesome [VDM sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDMSound) driver on Windows and start your game under Windows.  The driver will emulate Sound Blaster on any sound card that is installed in Windows; this was the only known option for newer sound cards that did not have any DOS drivers like SB 128 Live. However this will no longer work under pure DOS.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because it's vague and doesn't help with the issue at hand at all.

Comment: The question is about running in pure DOS, VDM sound is not relevant.

Comment: @knol I reedited the answer along with the DOS driver fix I found in my archives btw. the question is about running `DOS game (Crystal Caves)` with sound and not about running sound in pure DOS ... its just (s)he using "pure" DOS to test this (even if w9x DOS is far away from pure DOS) ... and what do you mean by vague?

Comment: I said it was vague because the original version of this answer only talked about Creative's own first-party cards. The edits are an improvement :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this issue which I had no idea about. After installing the driver from the other answer, the lines you point out were added to `autoexec.bat` automatically which is very nice.